# How to get md5 from multipart.File

Tags: go

In Go, what is the right way to get the md5 of *multipart.File?

Here is my code which retuened the wrong md5:

```
// GetFileMd5 count file's md5
// return md5 string
func GetFileMd5(file multipart.File) (md5Str string) {
    h := md5.New()
    if _, err := file.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
        log.Error("Get file md5 error: %v", err)
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(h, file); err != nil {
        log.Error("Get file md5 error: %v", err)
    }
    md5Str = hex.EncodeToString(h.Sum(nil))
    log.Debug("File md5 is: %s", md5Str)
    return md5Str
}
```

Comment: Your code looks alright, how come you're getting wrong md5?  In your code  just `return` is good enough, you can remove variable name.

Comment: Hi @jeevatkm , if I change multipart.File to File, and remove file.Seek(0, 0), it will return the right md5.  So I am really confused if I use the method Seek correctly.   And you are right, the variable name can be left out in this function.

Comment: Actually you can remove `Seek` call too. if you're getting file from request passing it to this method it will be always zeroth position.

Comment: Is there any particular need for you to use type `multipart.File` instead of  `os.File` or `io.Reader` for `GetFileMd5` method?

Comment: Because I am writing a web-server, this function get these file from http.Request.   Finally, I find the `io.Copy()` result is always change and different from file size. I find there is a thread function which is used for compressing the file, and they share the same file cursor in memory. I comment the thread, then this function can work well.

Comment: I think it's better to do saving the file to the disk and calculate the md5 from the file. If it's satisfy your requirement.

Comment: @jeevatkm The web-server do not save any files, the files will be uploaded to amazon s3.  So it maybe make things complex that saving the file from memory to the disk just to calculate the md5, and delete it at last.  Still appreciate for your suggestion, I will try to find a more comfortable way to do it.

Comment: Okay I understand, good luck.

Comment: @Flimzy I agree about hard to read. The question code snippet has defined variable in the out parameter. It that sense I made a comment. Thanks.

Comment: @jeevatkm I realize that, but even when defined in the out parameter, naked returns are discouraged except for extremely short functions (and even then, I eschew them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ok, but check, how you receive and store files. If you store them in memory, then you shouldn't call `Seek` method.

If you want to calculate hash of uploaded file and in the same time save it locally or upload to the cloud, then you can use [MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter).